# Asymptotic behaviour of $\prod_{p \leq x} (1 + 4/(3p) + C p^{-3/2})$

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I'm reading Montgomery and Vaughan and in it they state quite simply
\begin{equation}
\prod_{p \leq x} \left(1 + \frac{4}{3p} + \frac{C}{p^{3/2}} \right) \ll (\log x)^{4/3}
\end{equation}
as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and where $C$ is some constant. It states that it's using Mertens' formula so there should probably be some relation of the form
\begin{equation}
\prod_{p \leq x} \frac{1 + \frac{4}{3p} + \frac{C}{p^{3/2}}}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)^{4/3}} \ll 1
\end{equation}

but I can't quite get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the relation you wanted to write down, via Merten's $3$rd theorem, should be

$$\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{4/3}\left(1+\frac{4}{3p}+\frac{C}{p^{3/2}}\right) \ll 1.$$

Hint: we know $(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x+O(x^2)$ (for $x\approx0$) and when $\prod(1-p^{-s})$ converges.

Comment: Let me just check that I've got this right:
\begin{align}
\prod_{p \leq x} (1 - 1/p)(1 + 4/(3p) + Cp^{-4/3}) &= \prod_{p \leq x} (1 - 4/(3p) + O(p^{-2}))(1 + 4/(3p) + Cp^{-4/3})\\
&= \prod_{p \leq x} (1 + C'p^{-3/2})
\end{align}
for some constant $C'$. This corresponds to an Euler product expansion of a formal Dirichlet series given by $f(p) = p^{-1/2}$ and where $f(p^k) = 0$ for any $k \geq 2$. Therefore the above product equals
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac{\mu(n)^2}{n^{3/2}} \ll \zeta(3/2) < \infty
\end{equation}
giving the required result.

Comment: Yes, although that last equality should be something like $\ll$.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and tried to correct it but the site wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should just mimic the proof of Mertens' formula. We have that
\[\sum_{p \leq x} \log\left(1 + \frac{4}{3p} + \frac{C}{p^{3/2}}\right) = \frac{4}{3} \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} + \sum_{p \leq x}\left(\log\left(1 + \frac{4}{3p} + \frac{C}{p^{3/2}}\right) - \frac{4}{3p}\right),\]
and the first term is asymptotic to $\frac{4}{3} \log \log x$, while one can write the logarithm in terms of its power series in order to show that the second term is $o(1)$, from which the result follows.